# How to install wifi drivers in kali 2.0?

Tags: linux

In my kali 2.0 sana 64 bit
When I run the command "iwconfig" in root terminal I get an reply

> eth0 : no wireless extension found
>
> lo     : no wireless extension found

My laptops specs :

> IEEE 802.11 n/g/b wifi
> Asus X555LA - XX172D

when I tried " rfkill -f " it showed

> wifi : Asus wifi
> soft blocked : no
> When i entered Ispci -vnn | grep -inet it replied that there is "ispci" no such command both in root and normal terminal.

Comment: This isn't really an information security issue, more of a general computer support issue - you will probably get better answers from Superuser.SE

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state **which Linux distribution and version** (for example, Ubuntu 15.04, Debian Jessie, ...) you are using.

Comment: The first thing you need to post is the output of `lspci -vnn | grep -inet`. Later  I will have to ask for something more, depending on the output.